# Implementing pi calculus using STM in JAVA

Tags: stm, transactional-memory, pi-calculus

I want to implement `pi-calculus in JAVA. For concurrency I am using the **Deuce STM library**.
Changing the JAVA syntax would be difficult so I am planning to use annotated variables and generic functions/classes.

for eg.

```
    class Channel{
         private var1;
         private var2;
         @Atomic                  // This is handled by Deuce 
         public void Send(){
         }
         @Atomic
         public void Receive(){
         }
    }
```

So a channel will be an instance of this class.

I am confused on how to model processes so as to allow interaction between them via these channels.

Any help/suggestions ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please extend on what are the blocker you encountered?

Comment: I've updated the statement. Kindly put some light on the problem.